# How to update a RPM package in a RHEL yum repo?

Tags: yum, rhel6

I am managing a RHEL 6 yum repo, the repo source files were just a local copy from the disk ISO ,
and for some reason I need to replace a few RPM package in this repo by new version of RPMs,
I've tried:
1: put new RPM package in Packages dir
2: re-create the repo by "createrepo"

but any client when running yum install, it still got the old version of RPM,
how I can get it work as expected?

Comment: maybe clearing the yum cache like [here](https://kb.hivelocity.net/how-to-clear-the-yum-cache/)?

Answer (score 0):

use the  command :

createrepo --update

Sometimes you have a lot of packages in your repository and regenerating the meta data for each package when only a few packages have been added or changed is just too time consuming. This is where --update comes in handy. You run createrepo just like you did before but you pass the --update flag to it. Like this:
      createrepo --update /srv/my/repo